# Attach layer to a lambda via configuration file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to add in my amplify folder a config file to attach a layer to my lambdas.

As I do for custom-policies.js in function folders, I would like to write a configuration file that I can push on GIT repo, able to set up a layer without using the amplify interface.

Is it possible?